# Sum records and add note what was summed up in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table looks like this one:

```
company_Id    user_Id    price   sub_price
   123456      11111      200      NULL
   123456      11111      500      NULL
   456789      22222      300      NULL
```

And I want to consolidate records which has count(*) >= 2 into one row by summing  up the price but with note what was summed up in column sub_price. Desired output should look like this one:

```
 company_Id    user_Id    price   sub_price
   123456      11111      700      200,500
   456789      22222      300      300
```

Is there any simple approach how to achieve desired output? Many thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using MS SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one possible solution;
More info about concatenating multiple rows into single row you can find [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/)

```
DECALRE @tbl AS table (
    company_Id int
    ,user_Id int
    ,price int
    ,sub_price varchar(25)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl values (123456, 11111, 200, NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl values (123456, 11111, 500, NULL)
INSERT INTO @tbl values (456789, 22222, 300, NULL)


SELECT
    company_Id
    ,user_Id
    ,SUM(price) AS price
    ,STUFF(
        (SELECT ',' + cast(price as varchar)
        FROM @tbl
        WHERE company_Id = a.company_id
            AND user_Id = a.user_Id 
        FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,1,'') AS sub_price
FROM @tbl a
GROUP BY company_Id, user_Id
```

Comment: Thank you very much!! I like your approach!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `listagg` to turn the elements of a group into a string:

```
SELECT ...
     , LISTAGG(price, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY price) sub_price
  FROM ...
```

Although `listagg` is SQL standard, it is [not yet supported by all databases](http://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg#compatibility). However, most database offer similar functionality by a different name—e.g. `string_agg` in PostgreSQL and SQL Sever (since 2017) or `group_concat` in MySQL.

More info: http://modern-sql.com/feature/listagg (also showing alternatives if `listagg` is not supported)